# Shell script through Oozie

Tags: shell, validation, hadoop, sqoop, oozie

I am currently creating a workflow that will import data via sqoop on an automatic basis. What I am trying to do is verify that the number of lines (records) imported through this process is accurate; the validate parameter provided by sqoop does not work here because the sqoop job is NOT importing a single table.

I have created an action called "validation" which will call and execute a shell script called validation. This validation script does the following steps:

- Count and store the number of rows from DB source by use of sqoop eval and free-form query
- Concatenate and run a word count on the different partitions within the hdfs subdirectory; this is a looping function
- It will delete any partition that has zero lines
- It will then evaluate the two counts and force an exit code if it fails, and return if true

However, when I run it, I get the following error, which is NOT giving me the information I need:

```
2014-09-22 19:03:59,156  INFO ShellActionExecutor:539 - USER[v523043] GROUP[-] TOKEN[-] APP[voipImportToHDFS] JOB[0000359-140905180027053-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000359-140905180027053-oozie-oozi-W@validation] action completed, external ID [null]
2014-09-22 19:03:59,159  WARN ShellActionExecutor:542 - USER[v523043] GROUP[-] TOKEN[-] APP[voipImportToHDFS] JOB[0000359-140905180027053-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000359-140905180027053-oozie-oozi-W@validation] Launcher ERROR, reason: Main class [org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.ShellMain], exit code [1]
2014-09-22 19:03:59,177  INFO ActionEndXCommand:539 - USER[v523043] GROUP[-] TOKEN[-] APP[voipImportToHDFS] JOB[0000359-140905180027053-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000359-140905180027053-oozie-oozi-W@validation] end executor for wf action 0000359-140905180027053-oozie-oozi-W with wf job 0000359-140905180027053-oozie-oozi-W
2014-09-22 19:03:59,198  INFO ActionEndXCommand:539 - USER[v523043] GROUP[-] TOKEN[-] APP[voipImportToHDFS] JOB[0000359-140905180027053-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000359-140905180027053-oozie-oozi-W@validation] ERROR is considered as FAILED for SLA
```

My validation script uses commands:

- sqoop eval ...
- List item

hadoop fs -cat ...

Are there compatability issues that I am overlooking here? Do I need to configure something differently?

My validation script (in progress version):

```
for table in ${tables[*]}
do

    #Get the number of records from DB Exadata
    verifiedCount=$(sqoop eval --connect $3 --query "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $4.${tables[table]} WHERE INTRVL_DT = To_Date('$5')" | awk '/([0-9]+)/{print $2}')
    #echo "Total Number of Records " $verifiedCount

    #Count the number of rows imported


    totalRows=0
    for ((i=0;i<$mapJobs;i++)) {
        count[$i]=$(hadoop fs -cat $6$7/${tables[table]}/$8/$9/$10/part-m-0000$i | wc -l) 
        totalRows=$((totalRows + ${count[$i]}))
        #if value has 0 lines, remove the file from edgenode to limit overhead
        if [ ${count[$i]} -eq "0" ]
            then
                hadoop fs -rmr $6$7/${tables[table]}/$8/$9/$10/part-m-0000$i
                echo "Removing..."
            fi
    }
    #echo values
    if [ "$totalRows" -eq "$verifiedCount" ]
    then
        echo "evaluation=true"
        evaluation=true
    else
        echo "evaluation=false"
        evaluation=false
        exit 40
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Brute-force error debugging caused me to find the error with the following line:

```
hadoop fs -rmr $6$7/${tables[table]}/$8/$9/$10/part-m-0000$i
```

specifically, with the -rmr did not sit well with the environment, causing it to crash.